# REST API with method PATCH/UPDATE and resource ID

Tags: json, rest, api

I have to implement REST endpoints to update a resource.
I will use the methods PUT and PATCH (the latter used to send a json that has only the attributes to modify).

The payload of the calls will be a json that is parsed by Jackson.
Using  custom deserializers and converter,s the parser will create the correct instances of java beans.

I know that usually these endpoints will have in their URL the ID of the resource to update.

For the PATCH endpoint, I would prefer to send the ID of the resource in the json, together with all the other resources.

I can see PROS and CONS.

**CONS:** the URL looks like something that is updating the collection of resources and not a single resource,

**PROS:** the json contains all the necessary information and the parser can find the resource in the database and add the information that wasn't sent with the request.
This would simplify the code because the parser will return an object ready to use.

Comment: REST doesn't dictate what you send within the request nor if the URI targeting the resource to update has to contain the ID itself. Any answers are thus likely to represent only opinionated takes on that matter and thus make this question eligible for being closed as such. If your service only deals with JSON content though, I'd suggest to have a look into [JsonPatch](http://jsonpatch.com/). Please keep in mind though, that a soley JSON based Web API isn't actually what matches the basic idea of REST, but this is an other story

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, it would be better to pass the ID in the URL.
One of the main constraint of a REST API is the "Resource identification in requests": it should be possible to easily identify the resource modified looking the call.

It is not enough that the representation passed has the information necessary to identify the resource: it is also important that the identification is easy and does not require the knowlodege of internal details.